# studying nhibernate critieria queries

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

Is there any other site for studying critieria queries like http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Answer (score 1):

The [nhibernate.info](http://nhibernate.info) website has lot of docs.

Answer (score 1):

- [Knol by Fabio Maulo](http://openbook.galileocomputing.de/visual_csharp/)
- Some blog posts by Ayende

  - [Operator Overloading](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/08/04/NHibernateCriteriaAPIOperatorOverloading.aspx)
  - [Multi Queries](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/05/20/NHibernate-Multi-Criteria.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

One of the most helpful resources for me to learn more about NHibernate's Criteria API was definitely the 'Summer of NHibernate' screencast series (see [here](http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/)). Session 2 will show you how powerful it is.

The guy that created those series seriously rocks.